# Variable unable to receive data

Tags: typescript

I have one trainee.service.ts file where the code as shown as below

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { WebApiService, API_CMD } from "../../../theme/";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Trainee } from './trainee';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

@Injectable()
export class TraineeDataService {

trainee: Trainee[];
constructor(private webApi: WebApiService) {

}

getTrainee(): Trainee[] {
    console.log(this.trainee);
    return this.trainee;
}

getAllTrainee():void{
let url = API_CMD.GET_ALL_TRAINEE;
this.webApi.getData(url)
  .subscribe(res=>{
    this.trainee = res.json();
    console.log(this.trainee);
});
}

}}
```

Whenever I called `this.getTrainee()` at other place, the `trainee` variable here is undefined within the method, but the `console.log(this.trainee)` in `getAllTrainee()` do shows data. I can't figure out why?

Comment: You have to call getAllTrainee() and wait until the data is returned, before this.trainee is populated. Perhaps you are trying to call getTrainee() too early?

Comment: @Kokodoko but if i put all those service method in my component.ts, it functions well =(

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
trainee: Trainee[];
```

is only typecasting the property trainee not setting a value to it hence before calling the function it is undefined.

If it were to be defined as the following

```
trainee: Trainee[] = [];
```

Then the default value will be a blank array.

If you call the **getTrainee** function before the finalized call of ** getAllTrainee** then the value of trainee will be undefined but if you call the function **getTrainee** after the subscribe action has been fulfilled by the function **getAllTrainee** then it will not be undefined but will be the value of the response.

```
this.trainee = res.json(); //you have now assigned a value to trainee
console.log(this.trainee); //now it will not be undefined but will be the value you have fetched from API.
```